# LWJGL 2D Tile game using more than 50MB of RAM a secon

Tags: java, 2d, lwjgl, tile

So I am a relatively new to programming and I am trying to make 2D game using LWJGL.  I have made a background map using tiles in an array list, I then update the necessary things such as the player etc, then I draw them onto the screen, and update the screen. I have seen other people do this just fine but whenever I do it uses up almost 100 mb of RAM every second, causing my computer to freeze if the game runs for 30 seconds or less.  I am not sure if it's the drawing that is causing this memory usage or something else, I have checked to make sure no code is being ran without my knowledge of it, please if someone should tell me what is wrong that would be great.  I have provided the main classes used in my game, there about 10 total but I have only shown 3 as I think it is enough to get my point. I know some of the code could look much better but, like I said, I am new to all of this. Thank you!

BOOT CLASS

public class Boot {

```
public Boot() {
    beginSession();

    tile menu = new tile(0, 0, 1024, 1024, TileType.Menu);
    tile outline = new tile(0, 0, 395, 96, TileType.Outline);
    Display.sync(60);
    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        System.out.println("MENU");
        menu.Draw();
        if (Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            Display.destroy();
        }
        if (Mouse.getX() > 380 && Mouse.getX() < 650 && Mouse.getY() < 320 && Mouse.getY() > 250) {
            outline.setX(322);
            outline.setY(305);
            outline.Draw();
        }
        if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0) && Mouse.getX() > 380 && Mouse.getX() < 650 && Mouse.getY() < 320 && Mouse.getY() > 250) {
            new Play();

        }
        if (Mouse.getX() > 340 && Mouse.getX() < 700 && Mouse.getY() < 210 && Mouse.getY() > 130) {
            outline.setX(322);
            outline.setY(425);
            outline.Draw();
        }

        if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0) && Mouse.getX() > 340 && Mouse.getX() < 700 && Mouse.getY() < 210 && Mouse.getY() > 130) {
            new About();
        }
        Display.update();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Boot();
}
```

}

PLAY CLASS`

public class Play {

```
public Play() {
    //@formatter:off
    //MAPS//
    int[][] map0 = { 
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 }, };

    int[][] map1 = {
            { 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6 }, };

    int[][] map2 = { 
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0 }, };

    int[][] map3 = {
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
            { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 },
            { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 },
            { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 }, };
    //MAP FOUR//
    int[][] map3left1 = {
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
            { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 },
            { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 },
            { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 }, };
    //MAP FIVE//
    int[][] map3left2 = {
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
            { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 },
            { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 },
            { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 }, };
    //MAP SIX//
    int[][] map3left3 = {
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
            { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 },
            { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 },
            { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 }, };
    //@formatter:on

    TileGrid grid0 = new TileGrid(map0);
    TileGrid grid1 = new TileGrid(map1);
    TileGrid grid2 = new TileGrid(map2);
    TileGrid grid3 = new TileGrid(map3);
    TileGrid grid3left1 = new TileGrid(map3left1);
    TileGrid grid3left2 = new TileGrid(map3left2);
    TileGrid grid3left3 = new TileGrid(map3left3);

    // ALL TILES IN GAME THAT ARE ALWAYS NEEDED GO HERE//
    Asteriod a = new Asteriod(quickLoad("asteriodfour"), -100, 0, grid0, 64, 64, 10, 100);
    Lander l = new Lander(quickLoad("LunarLander"), grid0.getTile(7, 0), grid0, 240, 228, 0, 0);
    Wave wave = new Wave(15, a);
    Astronaut player = new Astronaut(quickLoad("astronaut"), l.getX(), 310, 256, 256);

    // LADNING THE LANDER//
    while (l.isLanded() == false) {
        Display.sync(60);
        gridType = 3;
        if (Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            Display.destroy();
        }

        switch (l.getMapType()) {
        case 0:
            grid0.Draw();
            break;
        case 1:
            grid1.Draw();
            break;
        case 2:
            grid2.Draw();
            break;
        case 3:
            grid3.Draw();
            break;
        }

        l.Draw();
        l.UpdateLander();

        if (l.isLanded() == false && l.isFirst()) {
            wave.UpdateAsteroid();
        } else {
            wave.getAsteriodList().clear();
        }

        if (wave.getColY() > 390 && l.getMapType() == 3) {
            wave.getAsteriodList().clear();
        }

        if (l.getX() - wave.getColX() < 35 && wave.getColX() - l.getX() < 95 && l.getY() - wave.getColY() < 35 && wave.getColY() - l.getY() < 200) {
            wave.explodeAsteroid();
            l.takeDamage();
        }

        Display.update();
    }
    onMoon = true;

    // PLAYER EVERYTHING//
    while (onMoon == true) {
        Display.sync(60);
        if (Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            Display.destroy();
        }


        if (player.getX() < 5 && gridType == 3) {
            gridType = 4;
            player.setX(1000);
        } 

        switch (gridType) {
        case 3: 
            grid3.Draw();
            l.Draw();
            l.UpdateLander();
            break;

        case 4 :
            grid3left1.Draw();
        }

        player.Draw();
        player.UpdateAstronaut();

        if (player.isLeft() == true) {
            player.setTexture(quickLoad("astronaut"));
        } else {
            player.setTexture(quickLoad("astronautRight"));
        }

        Display.update();
    }

}
```

}

LANDER CLASS

public class Lander extends Artist {

```
public Lander(Texture texture, tile startTile, TileGrid grid, int width, int height, float speed, int angle) {
    this.texture = texture;
    this.x = startTile.getX();
    this.y = startTile.getY();
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.angle = angle;
}

public void Draw() {
    drawQuadTexRotate(texture, x, y, width, height, angle);
}

//UPDATES LANDER//
public void UpdateLander() {

    tile forceField = new tile(685, 510, 256, 32, TileType.ForceField);
    tile forceFieldOff = new tile(745, offY, 64, 32, TileType.Off);
    tile forceFieldOn = new tile(755, onY, 32, 32, TileType.On);
    tile battery = new tile(13 * 64, 8 * 64, 96, 96, TileType.Battery8);
    tile outOfFuel = new tile(820, 480, outOfFuelX, 32, TileType.OutOfFuel);

    forceField.Draw();
    forceFieldOn.Draw();
    forceFieldOff.Draw();
    battery.setTexture(quickLoad(percentage()));
    outOfFuel.Draw();
    battery.Draw();

    screenMove();
    landerHealth();

    if (landed == false)
        y = (float) (y + 1.4);

    if (canMove == true) {
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {
            x -= 1;
            if (angle > -35) {
                angle -= 0.2;
            }
            fuelUsed += 0.1;
            if (fuelUsed > 70) {
                fuelLeft -= 1;
                fuelUsed = 0;
            }
        }

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)) {
            y -= 0.6;
            fuelUsed += 0.1;
            if (fuelUsed > 70) {
                fuelLeft -= 1;
                fuelUsed = 0;
            }

        }
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {
            if (angle < 25) {
                angle += 0.2;
            }
            x += 1;
            fuelUsed += 0.1;
            if (fuelUsed > 70) {
                fuelLeft -= 1;
                fuelUsed = 0;
            }

        }
        if (fuelLeft < 0.1) {
            outOfFuelX = 170;
            canMove = false;
        }
    }
}


//LANDER HEALTH ONLY RAN WHEN UPDATED//
public void landerHealth() {

    tile h = new tile(680, 540, 180, 96, TileType.Health100);

    if (health < 90 && health > 80) {
        h.setTexture(quickLoad("health90"));
        h.Draw();
    }
    if (health < 80 && health > 70) {
        h.setTexture(quickLoad("health80"));
        h.Draw();
    }
    if (health < 70 && health > 60) {
        h.setTexture(quickLoad("health70"));
        h.Draw();
    }
    if (health < 60 && health > 50) {
        h.setTexture(quickLoad("health60"));
        h.Draw();
    }
    if (health < 50 && health > 40) {
        h.setTexture(quickLoad("health50"));
        h.Draw();
    }
    if (health < 40 && health > 30) {
        h.setTexture(quickLoad("health40"));
        h.Draw();
    }
    if (health < 30 && health > 20) {
        h.setTexture(quickLoad("health30"));
        h.Draw();
    }
    if (health < 20 && health > 10) {
        h.setTexture(quickLoad("health20"));
        h.Draw();
    }
    if (health < 10 && health > 0) {
        h.setTexture(quickLoad("health10"));
        h.Draw();
    }
    if (health <= 0) {
        h.setTexture(quickLoad("health0"));
        h.Draw();
        landerExplode();
        canMove = false;
    }
    h.Draw();
}


//SCREEN MOVE ONLY RAN WHEN UPDATED//
public void screenMove() {
    System.out.println("SCREEN MOVE");
    if (landed == false) {
        if (y > 500 && mapType < 3) {
            mapType++;
            y -= 650;
        }
        if (mapType == 3) {
            if (y < 230 && y > 226 && angle < 4 && angle > -4) {

                canMove = false;
                landed = true;
                eX2 = x - 15;
                eY2 = y - 15;
                offY = 2000;
                onY = 540;

            }
            if (y > 234 && (angle > 4 || angle < -4)) {
                landerExplode();
            }
        }
    }
}


//ONLY RAN WHEN UPDATED, DEATH SCREEN NEEDED//
public void landerExplode() {
    if (landerExplodeCounter < 850) {
        if (first) {
            eX1 = x;
            eX2 = x - 15;
            eX3 = x;
            eY1 = y;
            eY2 = y - 15;
            eY3 = y;
            x = 2000;
            first = false;
        }
        System.out.println("EX");
        landerExplodeCounter++;
        tile landerp1 = new tile(x, y, 240, 228, TileType.LanderPart1);
        tile landerp2 = new tile(x, y, 240, 228, TileType.LanderPart2);
        tile landerp3 = new tile(x, y, 240, 228, TileType.LanderPart3);
        landerp1.setX(eX1 -= 0.7);
        landerp1.setY(eY1 -= 0.4);
        landerp2.setX(eX2 += 0.5);
        landerp2.setY(eY2 -= 0.2);
        landerp3.setX(eX3 -= 0.1);
        landerp3.setY(eY3 += 0.8);
        landerp1.Draw();
        landerp2.Draw();
        landerp3.Draw();

    }
}

//ONLY RAN WHEN UPDATED//
public void takeDamage() {
    System.out.println("TAKE DAMAGE");
    if (landed == false) {
        health = (float) (health - 5.5);
        System.out.println(health);
    }
}

//ONLY RAN WHEN UPDATED//
private String percentage() {
    System.out.println("PERCENTAGE");
    String name = "Battery";
    switch (fuelLeft) {
    case 8:
        name = name + "8";
        break;
    case 7:
        name = name + "7";
        break;
    case 6:
        name = name + "6";
        break;
    case 5:
        name = name + "5";
        break;
    case 4:
        name = name + "4";
        break;
    case 3:
        name = name + "3";
        break;
    case 2:
        name = name + "2";
        break;
    case 1:
        name = name + "1";
        break;
    case 0:
        name = name + "0";
        break;
    }
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Posting a code dump is not likely to get  you help from anyone...

Answer (score 0):

Is your code ever pausing? if it updates every time it runs through the while loop without stoping, its definitely gonna eat your ram.

Comment: How and where would you pause it?  Because doesn't it need to constantly need to be updating?

Comment: You may want to learn about threads.... but an immediate answer would be to use thread.sleep(milliseconds);

Comment: @chooky1441 No, 60 times per second is the commonly used number. More wouldn't let the eye notice any change, so this is enough most of the time. You can use Thread.sleep(number_of_milliseconds); to pause processing for the given time. 12-16 milliseconds should probably be enough.